# node gyp rebuild fail

Tags: npm, node-gyp

im trying to install a nodejs application but I keep getting the same error about "node-gyp" failing to rebuild.

I dont know a lot about nodejs, apart from I can get this to work on my local machine fine but I cant figure out why it wont run on the server.

Ubuntu 14.04
Node v0.12.5
npm v2.11.2

```
> ws@0.4.32 install /root/banquo-server/node_modules/node-phantom/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory `/root/banquo-server/node_modules/node-phantom/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
make: Leaving directory `/root/banquo-server/node_modules/node-phantom/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'

> ref@1.0.2 install /root/banquo-server/node_modules/exec-sync/node_modules/ffi/node_modules/ref
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/root/banquo-server/node_modules/exec-sync/node_modules/ffi/node_modules/ref/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 127
make: Leaving directory `/root/banquo-server/node_modules/exec-sync/node_modules/ffi/node_modules/ref/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-52-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /root/banquo-server/node_modules/exec-sync/node_modules/ffi/node_modules/ref
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-52-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! ref@1.0.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ref@1.0.2 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ref package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ref
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/banquo-server/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a conflict with an older package that is getting in the way.

Try below commands helped me to resolve the issue, might help you too... these commands might need **sudo** access

```
npm cache clean -f
npm install -g n
n stable
npm install npm -g
```

So above solves the problem when there is any conflict in packages version.... but by looking at logs it  says `make: g++: Command not found` Which means you need to install developer tools

Answer (score 0):

have you tried installing node-gyp via apt-get install:

```
apt-get install node-gyp
```

Answer (score 0):

The command g++ is not found, so you need to install the g++ package (along with build-essential which includes other packages that are required to build/compile programs):

`sudo apt-get install build-essential g++`

Answer (score 0):

`yarn install` fixed it for me, hope this helps